# How can I expose my kubernetes app in a nice domain name using ingress?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I installed both the nginx-ingress and cassandra helm charts onto AWS. I created a Route53 record so I can reach the loadbalancer at a nice DNS name such as `k8s.mydomain.me`.

If I create an ingress record with the following spec:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /cassandra
        backend:
          serviceName: cassandra
          servicePort: 9042
```

`k8s.mydomain.me/cassandra` resolves, but what I'd really want is `cassandra.k8s.mydomain.me:9042` to resolve instead. How would I get that to work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe by default Nginx Ingress uses port 80 and 443. So if you really want to use port 9042 externally, you will need to reconfigure your nginx-ingress

Personally I like the fact that my nginx-ingress uses port 80, so that I never have to specify the port.

**Single-Domain**

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 'cassandra.k8s.mydomain.me'
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: cassandra
          servicePort: 9042
```

**Multi-Domain**

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 'cassandra.k8s.mydomain.me'
    http: &cassandra_svc
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: cassandra
          servicePort: 9042
  - host: 'real.cassandra.k8s.mydomain.me'
    http: *cassandra_svc
```

Comment: i tried the single-domain approach earlier and couldn't get it to work where i only needed to refer to `cassandra.k8s.mydomain.me`. E.g. when using `curl` i needed to specify both that domain as well as the public URL for the load balancer.

Comment: @MikeChen generally when using this approach it is smart to configure your domain to work with wildcard DNS. Usually you enter a record for * and specify the ip of your kubernetes node which hosts nginx-ingress or to your load-balancer ip

Comment: @MikeChen alternatively you can create a single cname record for each subdomain that points to the node of your cluster which hosts nginx-ingress, or to your load balancer

Comment: If you have created DNS for a new domain, sometimes it takes time for it to propogate across the internet. You can test that your domain works by running `host cassandra.k8s.mydomain.me` or `dig cassandra.k8s.mydomain.me` from a linux terminal

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an ingress rule that is based on the [HTTP Host header](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting).

You'll need to create a CNAME record set on route 53 that point to your load balancer : `cassandra.k8s.mydomain.me -> k8s.mydomain.me`

Then create the ingress rule without specifying a path :

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 'cassandra.k8s.mydomain.me'
    http:
      paths:
        backend:
          serviceName: cassandra
          servicePort: 9042
```